# Invalid type signature for (:==) in haskell

Tags: haskell, types

If I define the following function:

```
(:==) :: a -> b -> (a,b)
x :== y = (x,y)
```

I get the error:

```
Op.hs:2:1: error:
    Invalid type signature: (:==) :: ...
    Should be of form <variable> :: <type>
  |
2 | (:==) :: a -> b -> (a,b)
  | ^^^^^
```

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: As a thumb rule, `:` is considered to be "uppercase" -- it can be used to start type and constructor names, but not other variables for values.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`(:==)` is not a valid symbol for a function or variable identifier in Haskell. Symbols starting with `:` are reserved for constructors (`data MyData a b = a :== b` is a valid alternative).
Either choose a different name for your function, or use `(,)` which is a perfectly valid function that does what your function does, or use something like the data type in the parentheses above.

Source: [Haskell 98 Report - Lexical Structure - Section 2.4](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/lexemes.html#sect2.4)

Answer (score 4):

`:==` is not a valid identifier for a function. Operator identifiers starting with a colon ':' are reserved for constructors.

Consider defining your own pair type instead:

```
data MyPair a b = a :== b
```

If you are constructing some kind of small domain specific embedded language, this is an opportunity to give a meaningful name to the type, to distinguish it from ordinary pairs.